# Memory addresses, pointers, variables, values - what goes on behind the scenes

Tags: variables, pointers, memory-address

This is going to be a pretty loaded question but ever since I started learning about pointers I've been very curious about what happens behind the scenes when a program is run.

As far as I know, computer memory is commonly thought of as a long strip of memory divided evenly into individual bytes. Certainly pictures such as the following evoke such a metaphor:

[image: p_to_c]
[image: pa]
[image: alloc]

One thing I've been wondering, what do the memory addresses themselves represent? I'm sure it's no coincidence that memory addresses appear as 8 digit hexadecimal values (eg/ 00EB5748). Why is this?

Furthermore, when I declare a variable x, what is happening at the memory level? Is the compiler simply reserving a random address (+however many consecutive addresses it needs for the variable type) for data storage?

Now suppose x is an unsigned int that occupies 2 bytes of memory (ie values ranging from 0 to 65536). When I declare x = 12, what is happening? What is it that I'm making equal to 12? When I draw conceptual diagrams, I usually have a box for an address (say &x) pointing to a variable (x) that occupies seemingly nothing, and I'm sure that can't be a fully accurate picture of what's going on.

And what's happening at the binary level? Is the address 00EB5748 treated as 111010110101011101001000 and storing a value of 12 somewhere, or 1100?

Mostly my confusion & curiosity stems from the relationship between memory addresses and actual values being declared (eg/ 12, 'a', -355.2). As another example, suppose our address 00EB5748 is pointing to a char 's' whose value is 115 according to ASCII charts. Is the address describing a position that stores the value 115 in 1 byte, by flipping the appropriate 1s and 0s at that position in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open any book. You will see pages. Every page has a number. Consecutive pages are numbered by consecutive numbers. Do you have any confusion with numbered pages? I think no. Then you should not have confusion with computer memory.
Books were main memory storage devices before computer era. Computer memory derived basic concept from books: book has pages -> computer memory has memory cells, book has page numbers -> computer memory has memory addresses.

- One thing I've been wondering, what do the memory addresses themselves represent?

Numbers. Every memory cell has number, like every page in book.

- Furthermore, when I declare a variable x, what is happening at the memory level? Is the compiler simply reserving a random address (+however many consecutive addresses it needs for the variable type) for data storage?

Memory manager marks some memory cells occupied and tells the address of first reserved cell to compiler. Compiler associates name and type of variable with this address. (This picture is from my head, it can be inaccurate).

- When I declare x = 12, what is happening?

When you declared variable `x`, memory cells were reserved for this variable. Now you write `12` into these memory cells. Note that `12` is binary coded in some way, depending on type of variable `x`. If `x` is unsigned int which occupies 2 memory cells, then one cell will contain 0, other will contain 12. Because binary integer representation of 12 is

```
0000 0000 0000 1100
|_______| |_______|
  cell      cell
```

If 12 is floating-point number it will be coded in other way.

Comment: Love the analogy between computer memory and books. Makes sense to me now!

Answer (score 1):

1. A memory address is simply the position of a given byte in memory. The zeroth byte is at 0x00000000. The tenth at 0x0000000A. The 65535th at 0x0000FFFF. And so on.
2. Local variables live on the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation)*. When compiling a block of code, the compiler counts how many bytes are needed to hold all the local variables, and then increments the stack pointer so that all the variables can fit below it (along with some other stuff like frame pointers and return addresses and whatnot). Then it just remembers that, for example, local variable x is at an offset -2 from the stack pointer, foo is at an offset -4 and so on, and uses those addresses whenever those variables are referenced in the following code.
3. Since the compiler knows that x is at address (stack pointer - 2), that's the location that is set to the value 12 when you do `x = 12`.
4. Not entirely sure if I understand this question, but say you want to read the memory at address 0x00EB5748. The control unit in the CPU reads the instruction, sees that it is a load instruction, and passes the address (in binary of course) to the load/store unit, along with some other junk like how many bytes to read. Then the LSU sends that address to some memory (probably L1 cache), and after a certain time gets the value 12 back. Then this data is available to, say, put in a register, or send to the ALU to do arithmetic, or whatever.
5. That seems to be accurate, yes. Going back to the first question, an address simply means "byte number 0xWHATEVER in memory".

Hope this clarified things a bit at least.

*I should probably explain the stack as well. A stack is a portion of memory reserved for local variables (and some other stuff). It starts at a fixed location in memory, and stops at the memory address contained in a special register called the stack pointer. To begin with, the stack is empty, so the stack pointer just contains the start of the stack. As you put more data on the stack, the SP is incremented. This means that you can always put more data on it simply by putting it at the address in the SP, and then incrementing the SP so that once again anything past that address is free memory.

Comment: Also, if anyone sees any factual errors please correct them. My sources include lectures I half-slept through years ago, stuff I may have read in a book or whatever idunno, dreams, hallucinations and more.